# How to remove lines containing any one of an array of strings from a file?

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I have a file like :

```
<string name="app_name">多系统启动免费版</string>
<string name="newitem">新建</string>
<string name="edit">编辑</string>
<string name="edits">编辑\u0020</string>
<string name="details">详情</string>
<string name="resize">改变大小</string>
<string name="seticon">设置图标</string>
<string name="delete">"删除 \u0020"</string>
<string name="reset">恢复出厂设置</string>
<string name="setdefault">设为默认</string>
<string name="description">多系统启动免费版</string>
<string name="nodata">没有发现虚拟系统镜像!!!</string>
```

and I want to remove lines containing `reset newitem details` from this. How do I make a script to remove these automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove lines where "reset", "newitem" or "details" appear *anywhere* in the strings, you can easily chain some `grep -v` statements together:

```xml
prompt:~/> cat file.txt | grep -v reset | grep -v newitem | grep -v details
<string name="app_name">多系统启动免费版</string>
<string name="edit">编辑</string>
<string name="edits">编辑\u0020</string>
<string name="resize">改变大小</string>
<string name="seticon">设置图标</string>
<string name="delete">"删除 \u0020"</string>
<string name="setdefault">设为默认</string>
<string name="description">多系统启动免费版</string>
<string name="nodata">没有发现虚拟系统镜像!!!</string>
```

The `-v` searches for the *inverse* of what grep would normally return. For a simple case like this, I think this approach would be easier than sed or awk.

Comment: Instead of 3 `grep`s, better to use `grep -v -e reset -e newitem -e details`.

Comment: Or `grep -Ev 'reset|newitem|details' inputfile` (also note the lack of `cat`).

Answer (score 2):

maybe

```
grep -vf <(printf "%s\n" reset newitem details) filename
```

Comment: I find it shocking that I have always been using a while read or for loop on a file to grep for a set of regex although the `-f` flag does exactly that. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Easiest is `grep -v -e reset -e newitem -e details`, as has been said. But for kicks, here's sed:

```
sed '/reset/d;/newitem/d;/details/d'
sed '/reset\|newitem\|details/d'
```

And awk:

```
awk '!/reset|newitem|details/'
awk '!/reset/ && !/newitem/ && !/details/'
awk '/reset/ || /newitem/ || /details/ { next } 1'
```